# Discord bot roles issue coding

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I was trying to code my bot to add a role to someone who doesn't have that role.... the rest of the code was working fine until I added the member.roles.add command.

It says `Missing Permission` however the bot has every possible permission on the server.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args) {
        if (message.member.roles.cache.has('754222099219873974')) {
            message.channel.send('pong');
        }
        else {
            message.channel.send('I see you do not have the right permission to use that command, let me change that for you :)');
            message.member.roles.add('754222099219873974');
        }

    }
}
```

This is the entire code for one command.

**Below is the error I get from the command terminal**

(node:68344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\Discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:68344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:68344) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the code not working? Are you getting an error? What behavior specifically results from the code you've posted?

Comment: the message "I see you do not have........." appears in the server......However it doesnt add the role............ The console gives me this error>>>

Comment: You cannot add a role if the role is above the bot's role in hierarchy

Comment: @Lioness100 but the bot has all the permissions including administrator active whereas ..... the role has a very few permissions

Comment: @Lioness100 whoa ok i got it........ i didnt know that the order mattered......... thanks a lot......appreciate it......

Comment: No problem . If you ever want to check role positions dynamically, you can use [`Role.comparePositionTo()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys I've solved the issue!

I didn't know that this order really mattered:

[image: I didn't know that this order really mattered]

The issue was that the bot was placed below the role i wanted to implement
All I had to do was drag the bot above the role and then it worked fine.

Thanks a lot!!! CHEERS!!